# Fetch data from comma separated string from JSON response and disable or enable button based on value in IONIC 3

Tags: arrays, json, angular, ionic3

I have a JSON response where for one parameter I have comma separated string like below

```
   this.dataList = [{ 
      "id":1,
      "name": "Ram",
      "total_slots": 3,
      "alloted_slot":"a1,a2,a3"
   },
   { 
      "id":2,
      "name": "Ashok"
      "total_slots": 3,
      "alloted_slot":"a1,a2"
   }]
```

I have a UI design where I need to display this data.Based on the total slots I need to display buttons, But **based on the `alloted_slot` value
   I need to disable and enable button. If alloted slots are a1 and a2 , then Slot 1 and Slot 2 will be disabled and Slot3 will be enabled**

```
 <ion-row *ngFor="let data of dataList">
        <ion-label>{{data.name}}</ion-label>
        <ion-row *ngIf="data.total_slots === 3">
                <ion-col col-4>
                <button ion-button>
                  Slot 1
                </button>
              </ion-col>
              <ion-col col-4>
                <button ion-button>
                  Slot 2
                </button>
              </ion-col>
               <ion-col col-4>
                <button ion-button>
                  Slot 3
                </button>
              </ion-col>

        </ion-row>
   </ion-row>
```

Can anyone help me how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let data of dataList">
    <ion-label>{{data.name}}</ion-label>
    <ion-row >
        <ion-col col-4>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let item of fakeArray(data.total_slots);let i = index">
                <button ion-button [disabled]="data.alloted_slot?.includes('a'+ (i+1))" (click)="getSelectedSlotValue('a'+ (i+1))">
                  Slot {{i + 1 }}
        </button>
            </ng-container>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-row>
```

TS:

```
  getSelectedSlotValue(slot: string) {
    alert("Select Slot :" + slot);
  }
```

**[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-rx4vpu?embed=1&file=app/app.html)**

Comment: May I know what is fakeArray? @Adrita Sharma

Comment: You can see it in the demo in app.component.ts

Comment: Its just a new array with dynamic length. fakeArray(length: number): Array<any> {
    if (length >= 0)
      return new Array(length);
  }

Comment: Btw, why do you need `*ngIf="data.total_slots === 3"`?

Comment: You were correct, *ngIf="data.total_slots === 3" ,this is not required, I was doing wrong.

Comment: Your's solution worked like a charm. Thank you so much.You saved my day.
One more doubt I have that is on button click how to pass the selected slot value.
Suppose clicking on a3, then in button click need to pass a3. Can you please help me @Adrita Sharma

Comment: @ananya Added the solution for `getSelectedSlotValue`. If this helped, please upvote and accept this answer

Comment: Suppose alloted_slot value is null,Like this "alloted_slot"=null, then how to check that disable condition.@Adrita Sharma

Comment: @ananya Just add safe navigation operator `?` Like this: `[disabled]="data.alloted_slot?.includes('a'+ (i+1))"`  Check the modified Demo